# Необходимо реализовать функцию, которая увеличивает время на заданное количество минут

Tags: javascript

Основные условия: 
1) На вход функция принимает 3 параметра: часы, минуты, интервал в минутах, на который нужно изменить время.
2) Переход в следующие сутки должен корректно обрабатываться.

На выходе я должен получить вот такую запись: addTime(12, 30, 30), '13:00', 'При добавлении 30 мин. к 12:30 получится 13:00');

Я совсем новичек в программировании, но в чем у меня ошибка в моем примитивном коде? Или есть проще вариант это сделать?

```
  module.exports = function (hours, minutes, interval) {
      return Number(hours>=0 && hours <=23), Number(minutes>=0 && minutes <=59), Number(interval);
      var a=hours && b=minutes+interval;

      if b === 59
        return a + 1;
      return parseFloat('a:b');

      if (b < 10) b = "0" + b;
      if (a < 10) a = "0" + a;   
    };
```

Comment: А не проще перевести сперва первые 2 параметра в минуты, прибавить, и выполнить обратное преобразование. Типа `tmp=hours*60+minutes+interval;return (tmp\60,':',tmp%60);`

Comment: тоже так думал, но как быть с переполнением?

Comment: С каким переполнением? часов больше, чем 24? ну дополнительно подели часы на 24 и верни только остаток, тоже мне проблема...

Comment: посмотрите аргументы при `new Date`, сложите входные параметры с вашими так - что б было "неправильное время" (или правильное, тут не важно) в аргументах new. В полученом обьекте дата-время будет уже правильно учтён сдвиг по времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вернуть строку, содержащую два числа через двоеточие. Для этого вам нужно вычислить новые значения часов и минут, используя оператор "остаток от деления" % Таким образом получаем:

```js
function timeIncrement(hours, min, interval){
  const newMin = (min + interval) % 60; // остаток от деления на 60
  const newHours = (hours + Math.floor((min + interval)/60)) % 24;  // Тут мы используем библиотечную функцию Math.floor для округления в меньшую сторону
  return `${newHours}:${newMin}`;  // составляем строку из полученных значений
}

// Проверяем:
console.log(timeIncrement(13, 30, 40));
console.log(timeIncrement(23, 30, 40));
console.log(timeIncrement(10, 0, 320));
```

Comment: Есть более простое решение.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я постарался наглядно объяснить решение задачи человеку, который только начинает изучать программирование

Answer (score 0):

Есть более "простое" решение. При создании обьект дата, при переполнении параметров JS сам делает поправки вперёд во времени или назад, при этом не нужно знать сколько в часе минут, в дне часов, и когда высокосный год. Приведу пример чисто для даного случая

```
function  timeIncrement(hours, min, interval){
  var d =new Date(2000,1,1,hours,min + interval);
  return ('0'+d.getHours()).slice(-2)+':' + ('0'+ d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  }
```

Про `new Date` можно почитать [тут](http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)